# How do we read the first character of a string input?

Tags: c++

For example, a user enters John as his name and i want to print just the first letter which is 'J'. How do we do that?

Thanks in advance..✌✌

Comment: Can you pliz elaborate. I'm not  familiar with the  [] operator...Newbie here.

Comment: Of course, `string` is an array of chars (`const char*`). So you can access it's elements by their index and [] operator. first char would be `string[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::cin` to get name, and use operator [] to access character you want. First character has index 0. So first letter of name is `name[0]`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;
    if (!name.empty())
    {
        std::cout << name[0];
    }
}
```

Also check if string is not empty.

Comment: Always check that the string is not empty before calling operator [] to avoid problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::string::at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/) function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string str ("Test string");
 std::cout << str.at(0);
}
```